# Combine Date Ranges in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of records in Python with an id, at least one attribute, and a set of date ranges.  I would like code that takes each id, and combines all the records where the attributes match and there is no gap in the date range.

By no gap in date range, I mean that the end date of one record is greater than or equal to the next record for that id.

For instance, a record with id "10", start date "2016-01-01" and end date "2017-01-01" could be merged with another record with that id, a start date of "2017-01-01", and an end date of "2018-01-01", but it could NOT be merged with a record that started on "2017-01-10", because there'd be a gap from 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-09.

Here are some examples --

Have:

```
FruitID,FruitType,StartDate,EndDate
1,Apple,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
1,Apple,2016-01-01,2017-01-01
1,Apple,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
2,Orange,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
2,Orange,2016-05-31,2017-01-01
2,Orange,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
3,Banana,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
3,Banana,2016-01-01,2017-01-01
3,Blueberry,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
4,Mango,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
4,Kiwi,2016-09-15,2017-01-01
4,Mango,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
```

Want:

```
FruitID,FruitType,NewStartDate,NewEndDate
1,Apple,2015-01-01,2018-01-01
2,Orange,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
2,Orange,2016-05-31,2018-01-01
3,Banana,2015-01-01,2017-01-01
3,Blueberry,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
4,Mango,2015-01-01,2016-01-01
4,Kiwi,2016-09-15,2017-01-01
4,Mango,2017-01-01,2018-01-01
```

My current solution is below.  It provides the results I'm looking for, but performance doesn't seem great for large datasets.  Also, my impression is that you generally want to avoid iterating over individual rows of a dataframe when possible.  Thank you very much for any assistance you can provide!

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse

have = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('FruitID', [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]),
                                ('FruitType', ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Blueberry', 'Mango', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']),
                                ('StartDate', [parse(x) for x in ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-05-31',
                                                                  '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-09-15', '2017-01-01']]),
                                ('EndDate', [parse(x) for x in ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01',
                                                                '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01']])
                                ])

have.sort_values(['FruitID', 'StartDate'])

rowlist = []
fruit_cur_row = None

for row in have.itertuples():
    if fruit_cur_row is None:
        fruit_cur_row = row._asdict()
        fruit_cur_row.update(NewStartDate=row.StartDate, NewEndDate=row.EndDate)

    elif not(fruit_cur_row.get('FruitType') == row.FruitType):
        rowlist.append(fruit_cur_row)

        fruit_cur_row = row._asdict()
        fruit_cur_row.update(NewStartDate=row.StartDate, NewEndDate=row.EndDate)

    elif (row.StartDate <= fruit_cur_row.get('NewEndDate')):
        fruit_cur_row['NewEndDate'] = max(fruit_cur_row['NewEndDate'], row.EndDate)
    else:
        rowlist.append(fruit_cur_row)
        fruit_cur_row = row._asdict()
        fruit_cur_row.update(NewStartDate=row.StartDate, NewEndDate=row.EndDate)

rowlist.append(fruit_cur_row)
have_mrg = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rowlist)
print(have_mrg[['FruitID', 'FruitType', 'NewStartDate', 'NewEndDate']])
```

Comment: Could you explain what "no gap in the date range" means? I am having trouble understanding the question. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my post to include more detail on "no gap" to try and clarify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a nested `groupby` approach:

```
def merge_dates(grp):
    # Find contiguous date groups, and get the first/last start/end date for each group.
    dt_groups = (grp['StartDate'] != grp['EndDate'].shift()).cumsum()
    return grp.groupby(dt_groups).agg({'StartDate': 'first', 'EndDate': 'last'})

# Perform a groupby and apply the merge_dates function, followed by formatting.
df = df.groupby(['FruitID', 'FruitType']).apply(merge_dates)
df = df.reset_index().drop('level_2', axis=1)
```

Note that this method assumes your dates are already sorted.  If not, you'll need to use `sort_values` on your DataFrame first.  This method may not work if you have nested date spans.

The resulting output:

```
   FruitID  FruitType   StartDate     EndDate
0        1      Apple  2015-01-01  2018-01-01
1        2     Orange  2015-01-01  2016-01-01
2        2     Orange  2016-05-31  2018-01-01
3        3     Banana  2015-01-01  2017-01-01
4        3  Blueberry  2017-01-01  2018-01-01
5        4       Kiwi  2016-09-15  2017-01-01
6        4      Mango  2015-01-01  2016-01-01
7        4      Mango  2017-01-01  2018-01-01
```

Comment: This approach seems like the cleanest way to approach the problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a really good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Great answer [root](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339965/root). I have modified your function, so that now it works also when date ranges are intersected. Maybe it will help someone.

```
def merge_dates(grp):
    dt_groups = (grp['StartDate'] > grp['EndDate'].shift()).cumsum()
    grouped = grp.groupby(dt_groups).agg({'StartDate': 'min', 'EndDate': 'max'})
    if len(grp) == len(grouped):
        return grouped
    else:
        return merge_dates(grouped)
```

Comment: Is there way to speed up this function for large datasets (>4M rows) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with...

```
df = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['FruitID', 'FruitType'], var_name='WhichDate', value_name='Date')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['FruitType', 'Date']).drop_duplicates(['FruitType', 'Date'])
df = df.assign(Counter = np.nan)
StartDf = df[df['WhichDate']=='StartDate']
StartDf = StartDf.assign(Counter=np.arange(len(StartDf)))
df[df['WhichDate']=='StartDate'] = StartDf
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
s = df.groupby(['Counter', 'FruitID', 'FruitType']).agg({'Date': [min, max]}).rename(columns={'min': 'NewStartDate', 'max': 'NewEndDate'})
s.columns = s.columns.droplevel()
s = s.reset_index()
del s['Counter']
s = s.sort_values(['FruitID', 'FruitType']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which outputs...

```
   FruitID  FruitType NewStartDate NewEndDate
0        1      Apple   2015-01-01 2018-01-01
1        2     Orange   2015-01-01 2016-01-01
2        2     Orange   2016-05-31 2018-01-01
3        3     Banana   2015-01-01 2017-01-01
4        3  Blueberry   2017-01-01 2018-01-01
5        4       Kiwi   2016-09-15 2017-01-01
6        4      Mango   2015-01-01 2016-01-01
7        4      Mango   2017-01-01 2018-01-01
```

**Explanation**

First, I recreated your dataframe.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'FruitID' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'FruitType': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana',
                                   'Blueberry', 'Mango', 'Kiwi',
                                   'Mango'],
            'StartDate': ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-05-31',
                          '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01',
                          '2016-09-15', '2017-01-01'],
            'EndDate' : ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01',
                         '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01',
                         '2018-01-01']})
```

Next, I used pandas `melt` function to reshape the data to long format.

```
df = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['FruitID', 'FruitType'], var_name='WhichDate', value_name='Date')
```

Then, I sort by Date for each Fruit Type and remove any rows with duplicate Dates

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['FruitType', 'Date']).drop_duplicates(['FruitType', 'Date'])
```

I create a helper column used to mark each row with a StartDate. We will need to do this before doing a `groupby`. Then use `fillna` to help partition the groups.

```
df = df.assign(Counter = np.nan)
StartDf = df[df['WhichDate']=='StartDate']
StartDf = StartDf.assign(Counter=np.arange(len(StartDf)))
df[df['WhichDate']=='StartDate'] = StartDf
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Finally, we use `groupby` and `agg` to get the `min` and `max` dates for each partition.

```
s = df.groupby(['Counter', 'FruitID', 'FruitType']).agg({'Date': [min, max]}).rename(columns={'min': 'NewStartDate', 'max': 'NewEndDate'})
s.columns = s.columns.droplevel()
s = s.reset_index()
del s['Counter']
s = s.sort_values(['FruitID', 'FruitType']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This seems very close, but the output seems to be structured differently than I'm used to.  When I run s = s.sort_values(['FruitID', 'FruitType'])
print(s.info()) ), the NewStartDate and NewEndDate fields seem to be on a different level (which I'm not familiar with) as the ids?

Comment: Please see the update to my code. I added a line that will drop 'Date' from the multi-level column index