# Combine date ranges in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, date-range

I have a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267366/combine-date-ranges-in-pandas-dataframe).

However, I am dealing with a huge dataset. I was trying to see if I can do the same thing in PySpark instead of pandas. Below is the solution in pandas. Can this be done in PySpark?

```
def merge_dates(grp):
    # Find contiguous date groups, and get the first/last start/end date for each group.
    dt_groups = (grp['StartDate'] != grp['EndDate'].shift()).cumsum()
    return grp.groupby(dt_groups).agg({'StartDate': 'first', 'EndDate': 'last'})

# Perform a groupby and apply the merge_dates function, followed by formatting.
df = df.groupby(['FruitID', 'FruitType']).apply(merge_dates)
df = df.reset_index().drop('level_2', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `Window` and `lag` function to calculate the contiguous groups and then aggregate those in a similar way as the `Pandas` function you shared. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


# EXAMPLE DATA -----------------------------------------------

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('FruitID', [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]),
                                ('FruitType', ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Blueberry', 'Mango', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']),
                                ('StartDate', [parse(x) for x in ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-05-31',
                                                                  '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-09-15', '2017-01-01']]),
                                ('EndDate', [parse(x) for x in ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01',
                                                                '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01']])
                                ])

pdf.sort_values(['FruitID', 'StartDate'])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)


# FIND CONTIGUOUS GROUPS AND AGGREGATE ---------------------

w = Window.partitionBy("FruitType").orderBy("StartDate")
contiguous = F.when(F.datediff(F.lag("EndDate", 1).over(w),F.col("StartDate"))!=0,F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
df = (df
      .withColumn('contiguous_grp', F.sum(contiguous).over(w))
      .groupBy('FruitType','contiguous_grp')
      .agg(F.first('StartDate').alias('StartDate'),F.last('EndDate').alias('EndDate'))
      .drop('contiguous_grp'))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|FruitType|          StartDate|            EndDate|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   Orange|2015-01-01 00:00:00|2016-01-01 00:00:00|
|   Orange|2016-05-31 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:00:00|
|   Banana|2015-01-01 00:00:00|2017-01-01 00:00:00|
|     Kiwi|2016-09-15 00:00:00|2017-01-01 00:00:00|
|    Mango|2015-01-01 00:00:00|2016-01-01 00:00:00|
|    Mango|2017-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:00:00|
|    Apple|2015-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:00:00|
|Blueberry|2017-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:00:00|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The Florian's answer does not distinguish between date ranges inside other date ranges and doesn't cover other important cases, so below I provide several modified versions.

When combining date ranges, these are the points to take into account:

- ranges inside other ranges
- null values
- acceptable size of the gap between the date ranges (do you need "touching" date ranges to be combined too?)

All the 4 following scripts work with ranges inside other ranges, but they differ in the other two criteria, that's why there are several variations.

---

**Option 1** - when null dates may exist and both "touching" (consecutive) and overlapping date ranges need to be combined

<sup>null in column `start_date` is considered as the earliest date and in `end_date` – the latest</sup>

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start_date")
max_end = F.when(~F.expr("any(end_date is null)").over(w), F.max("end_date").over(w))
contiguous = F.when(F.datediff(F.lag(max_end).over(w), "start_date") < -1, 1).otherwise(0)
df = (df
    .withColumn("contiguous_grp", F.sum(contiguous).over(w))
    .groupBy("id", "contiguous_grp")
    .agg(
        F.first("start_date").alias("start_date"),
        F.when(~F.expr("any(end_date is null)"), F.max("end_date")).alias("end_date"))
    .drop("contiguous_grp")
)
```

Test dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("separate",            "2022-01-01", "2022-01-09"),
     ("separate",            "2022-01-11", "2022-01-20"),
     ("consecutive",         "2022-02-01", "2022-02-10"),
     ("consecutive",         "2022-02-11", "2022-02-20"),
     ("overlap by 1",        "2022-03-01", "2022-03-11"),
     ("overlap by 1",        "2022-03-11", "2022-03-20"),
     ("overlap by 2",        "2022-04-01", "2022-04-12"),
     ("overlap by 2",        "2022-04-11", "2022-04-20"),
     ("inside",              "2022-05-01", "2022-05-20"),
     ("inside",              "2022-05-02", "2022-05-19"),
     ("common_start",        "2022-06-01", "2022-06-20"),
     ("common_start",        "2022-06-01", "2022-06-19"),
     ("common_end",          "2022-07-01", "2022-07-20"),
     ("common_end",          "2022-07-02", "2022-07-20"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-01", "2022-08-19"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-08", "2022-08-12"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-15", "2022-08-20"),
     ("n: separate",                 None, "2022-01-09"),
     ("n: separate",         "2022-01-11",         None),
     ("n: consecutive",              None, "2022-02-10"),
     ("n: consecutive",      "2022-02-11",         None),
     ("n: overlap by 1",             None, "2022-03-11"),
     ("n: overlap by 1",     "2022-03-11",         None),
     ("n: overlap by 2",             None, "2022-04-12"),
     ("n: overlap by 2",     "2022-04-11",         None),
     ("n: inside",                   None,         None),
     ("n: inside",           "2022-05-02", "2022-05-19"),
     ("n: common_start",             None, "2022-06-20"),
     ("n: common_start",             None, "2022-06-19"),
     ("n: common_end",       "2022-07-01",         None),
     ("n: common_end",       "2022-07-02",         None),
     ("n: overlap grp of 3",         None,         None),
     ("n: overlap grp of 3", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-12"),
     ("n: overlap grp of 3", "2022-08-15",         None)],
    [ "id",                  "start_date",   "end_date"])
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|                 id|start_date|  end_date|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|         common_end|2022-07-01|2022-07-20|
|       common_start|2022-06-01|2022-06-20|
|        consecutive|2022-02-01|2022-02-20|
|             inside|2022-05-01|2022-05-20|
|      n: common_end|2022-07-01|      null|
|    n: common_start|      null|2022-06-20|
|     n: consecutive|      null|      null|
|          n: inside|      null|      null|
|    n: overlap by 1|      null|      null|
|    n: overlap by 2|      null|      null|
|n: overlap grp of 3|      null|      null|
|        n: separate|      null|2022-01-09|
|        n: separate|2022-01-11|      null|
|       overlap by 1|2022-03-01|2022-03-20|
|       overlap by 2|2022-04-01|2022-04-20|
|   overlap grp of 3|2022-08-01|2022-08-20|
|           separate|2022-01-01|2022-01-09|
|           separate|2022-01-11|2022-01-20|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

---

**Option 2** - when null dates may exist and only overlapping date ranges need to be combined ("touching"/consecutive ranges don't need to be combined)

<sup>Same as above: null in column `start_date` is considered as the earliest date and in `end_date` – the latest</sup>

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start_date")
max_end = F.when(~F.expr("any(end_date is null)").over(w), F.max("end_date").over(w))
contiguous = F.when(F.datediff(F.lag(max_end).over(w), "start_date") < 0, 1).otherwise(0)
df = (df
    .withColumn("contiguous_grp", F.sum(contiguous).over(w))
    .groupBy("id", "contiguous_grp")
    .agg(
        F.first("start_date").alias("start_date"),
        F.when(~F.expr("any(end_date is null)"), F.max("end_date")).alias("end_date"))
    .drop("contiguous_grp")
)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|                 id|start_date|  end_date|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|         common_end|2022-07-01|2022-07-20|
|       common_start|2022-06-01|2022-06-20|
|        consecutive|2022-02-01|2022-02-10|
|        consecutive|2022-02-11|2022-02-20|
|             inside|2022-05-01|2022-05-20|
|      n: common_end|2022-07-01|      null|
|    n: common_start|      null|2022-06-20|
|     n: consecutive|      null|2022-02-10|
|     n: consecutive|2022-02-11|      null|
|          n: inside|      null|      null|
|    n: overlap by 1|      null|      null|
|    n: overlap by 2|      null|      null|
|n: overlap grp of 3|      null|      null|
|        n: separate|      null|2022-01-09|
|        n: separate|2022-01-11|      null|
|       overlap by 1|2022-03-01|2022-03-20|
|       overlap by 2|2022-04-01|2022-04-20|
|   overlap grp of 3|2022-08-01|2022-08-20|
|           separate|2022-01-01|2022-01-09|
|           separate|2022-01-11|2022-01-20|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

---

**Option 3** - when null dates don't exist and both "touching" (consecutive) and overlapping date ranges need to be combined

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start_date")
max_end = F.max("end_date").over(w)
contiguous = F.when(F.datediff(F.lag(max_end).over(w), "start_date") < -1, 1).otherwise(0)
df = (df
    .withColumn("contiguous_grp", F.sum(contiguous).over(w))
    .groupBy("id", "contiguous_grp")
    .agg(F.first("start_date").alias("start_date"), F.max("end_date").alias("end_date"))
    .drop("contiguous_grp")
)
```

Test dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("separate",            "2022-01-01", "2022-01-09"),
     ("separate",            "2022-01-11", "2022-01-20"),
     ("consecutive",         "2022-02-01", "2022-02-10"),
     ("consecutive",         "2022-02-11", "2022-02-20"),
     ("overlap by 1",        "2022-03-01", "2022-03-11"),
     ("overlap by 1",        "2022-03-11", "2022-03-20"),
     ("overlap by 2",        "2022-04-01", "2022-04-12"),
     ("overlap by 2",        "2022-04-11", "2022-04-20"),
     ("inside",              "2022-05-01", "2022-05-20"),
     ("inside",              "2022-05-02", "2022-05-19"),
     ("common_start",        "2022-06-01", "2022-06-20"),
     ("common_start",        "2022-06-01", "2022-06-19"),
     ("common_end",          "2022-07-01", "2022-07-20"),
     ("common_end",          "2022-07-02", "2022-07-20"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-01", "2022-08-19"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-08", "2022-08-12"),
     ("overlap grp of 3",    "2022-08-15", "2022-08-20")],
    [ "id",                  "start_date",   "end_date"])
```

Result:

```
+----------------+----------+----------+
|              id|start_date|  end_date|
+----------------+----------+----------+
|      common_end|2022-07-01|2022-07-20|
|    common_start|2022-06-01|2022-06-20|
|     consecutive|2022-02-01|2022-02-20|
|          inside|2022-05-01|2022-05-20|
|    overlap by 1|2022-03-01|2022-03-20|
|    overlap by 2|2022-04-01|2022-04-20|
|overlap grp of 3|2022-08-01|2022-08-20|
|        separate|2022-01-01|2022-01-09|
|        separate|2022-01-11|2022-01-20|
+----------------+----------+----------+
```

---

**Option 4** - when null dates don't exist and only overlapping date ranges need to be combined ("touching"/consecutive ranges don't need to be combined)

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start_date")
max_end = F.max("end_date").over(w)
contiguous = F.when(F.datediff(F.lag(max_end).over(w), "start_date") < 0, 1).otherwise(0)
df = (df
    .withColumn("contiguous_grp", F.sum(contiguous).over(w))
    .groupBy("id", "contiguous_grp")
    .agg(F.first("start_date").alias("start_date"), F.max("end_date").alias("end_date"))
    .drop("contiguous_grp")
)
```

Result:

```
+----------------+----------+----------+
|              id|start_date|  end_date|
+----------------+----------+----------+
|      common_end|2022-07-01|2022-07-20|
|    common_start|2022-06-01|2022-06-20|
|     consecutive|2022-02-01|2022-02-10|
|     consecutive|2022-02-11|2022-02-20|
|          inside|2022-05-01|2022-05-20|
|    overlap by 1|2022-03-01|2022-03-20|
|    overlap by 2|2022-04-01|2022-04-20|
|overlap grp of 3|2022-08-01|2022-08-20|
|        separate|2022-01-01|2022-01-09|
|        separate|2022-01-11|2022-01-20|
+----------------+----------+----------+
```