# pyspark pandas UDF merging date ranges in multiple rows

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am modifying the function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267366/combine-date-ranges-in-pandas-dataframe) to work with pyspark.

Input

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data_in = spark.createDataFrame([
    [1, "2017-1-1", "2017-6-30"], [1, "2017-1-1", "2017-1-3"], [1, "2017-5-1", "2017-9-30"],
    [1, "2018-5-1", "2018-9-30"], [1, "2018-5-2", "2018-10-31"], [1, "2017-4-1", "2017-5-30"],
    [1, "2017-10-3", "2017-10-3"], [1, "2016-12-5", "2016-12-31"], [1, "2016-12-1", "2016-12-2"],
    [2, "2016-12-1", "2016-12-2"], [2, "2016-12-3", "2016-12-25"]
  ], schema=["id","start_dt","end_dt"])

data_in = data_in.select("id", F.to_date("start_dt","yyyy-M-d").alias("start_dt"), 
               F.to_date("end_dt","yyyy-M-d").alias("end_dt")).sort(["id","start_dt","end_dt"])
```

Aggregate function to apply

```
from datetime import datetime

mydt = datetime(1970,1,1).date()
def merge_dates(grp):
  dt_groups = ((grp["start_dt"]-grp["end_dt"].shift(fill_value=mydt)).dt.days > 1).cumsum()
  grouped = grp.groupby(dt_groups).agg({"start_dt":"min", "end_dt":"max"})
  return grouped if len(grp)==len(grouped) else merge_dates(grouped)
```

Testing using Pandas

```
df = data_in.toPandas()
df.groupby("id").apply(merge_dates).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Output

```
   id    start_dt      end_dt
0   1  2016-12-01  2016-12-02
1   1  2016-12-05  2017-09-30
2   1  2017-10-03  2017-10-03
3   1  2018-05-01  2018-10-31
4   2  2016-12-01  2016-12-25
```

When I try to run this using Spark

```
data_out = data_in.groupby("id").applyInPandas(merge_dates, schema=data_in.schema)
display(data_out)
```

I get the following error

```
PythonException: 'RuntimeError: Number of columns of the returned pandas.DataFrame doesn't match specified schema. Expected: 3 Actual: 2'. Full traceback below:
```

When I change schema to data_in.schema[1:]  I get back only the date columns which are computed correctly (matches the Pandas output) but does not return the field `id` - which is obviously required.  How can I fix this so that the final output has the `id` as well?

Comment: The return value of `merge_dates` has only two columns: `start_dt` and `end_dt`. The `id` column is neither part of the grouping column(s) nor part of the aggregation expressions. But I would not try to fix this. Ankys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69456519/2129801) is shorter and faster than the Pandas approach.

Comment: not sure what you mean by `id` column is not part of the grouping column.  I do have `data_in.groupby("id")` - does it need to be specified differently?

Comment: I meant the grouping operation inside of `merge_dates`. Simply print out `grouped` inside the function. This Pandas dataframe has no column named `id`.

Comment: but that is syntax they seem to be suggesting https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html  In your opinion is there an error in the way the agg has been defined?

Comment: the issue is the return value of `merge_dates`. This dataframe does not contain the `id` column but it should. But just go with anky's solution...

Comment: ah...I see your point.  Adding  `{"id":"first", "start_dt":... ...}`  to the dictionary fixes the issue for Spark.  Of course now pandas doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With spark only, if we replicate what you have in pandas, it would look like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w1 = w.rangeBetween(W.unboundedPreceding,0)

out = (data_in.withColumn("helper",F.datediff(F.col("start_dt"),
                                    F.lag("end_dt").over(w))>1)
     .fillna({"helper":True})
     .withColumn("helper2",F.sum(F.col("helper").cast("int")).over(w1))
     .groupBy("id","helper2").agg(F.min("start_dt").alias("start_dt"),
                    F.max("end_dt").alias("end_dt")
                    )
.drop("helper2"))
```

---

```
out.show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|  start_dt|    end_dt|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2016-12-01|2016-12-02|
|  1|2016-12-05|2017-09-30|
|  1|2017-10-03|2017-10-03|
|  1|2018-05-01|2018-10-31|
|  2|2016-12-01|2016-12-25|
+---+----------+----------+
```

---

Note that this assumes that `mydt = datetime(1970,1,1).date()` is just a placeholder for nulls when shifting the values, .i have used fillna as True for same. if not you can fillna right after the `lag` which is the same as shift

Comment: I updated the input and output with id=2.  Your approach does not seem to work - can you please update your code so that it works with this example. Thx.

Comment: @ironv Apologies. I forgot to include `id` column in the grouper. Edited now